# Comparing Hardware Solutions for Transferring 8mm film to Digital?

Tags: analog, digital

I'm looking to better understand the various 8mm film silent movie scanning solutions available.  Can anyone shed light on the differences between [Moviestuff](http://www.moviestuff.tv/moviestuff_products_pricing.html) (appears inferior to me) and [MWA](https://mwa-nova.com/#our-products) (appears superior to me).  Are there other vendors that should also be considered?  I also see the Lasergraphics Scanstation.

How have they varied over time?  Has the technology changed much in recent years?  Has the technology gotten past the point of retrieving all the information in 8mm film?